# Exception Handling in SQL Server: Reject non-integer input

Tags: sql-server, exception

I'm trying to write a SQL commands within a stored procedure that allows me to take a VARCHAR input, evaluate to see whether it is an integer. If it is not, then it has to set a boolean value to false: 
So I want to write the following logic:

```
IF @parameter <> an int
    SET isInt = FALSE
```

I read the TRY/CATCH article but I just don't know how to do it in SQL: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms175976.aspx

Comment: Hmm. Why? Why are you passing an integer value as a `varchar`? Have you stepped back a bit and thought about whether what you're doing actually makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ISNUMERIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) function to test whether the input is numeric or not.

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC(@parameter) as output
```

As numeric value can also be `bigint`,`smallint`, `decimal` etc. So to compare only Integer you can try something like this (credit to [this blog)](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6423)

```
SELECT IsNumeric(@parameter + '.0e0') as integerOutput
```

Comment: Close, but not good enough. There's a lot of numeric values that aren't integers. `isnumeric('12.8')` still returns `1`.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is notorious for returning TRUE for things that have nothing to do with numbers in common wisdom. Read http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76834/what-is-the-logic-behind-isnumeric-for-certain-special-characters

Comment: could someone "THUMB UP" my question so that I can THUMB UP your answers please? I don't have enough "reputation" so I cannot score-UP your great answers and this makes me sad!

Answer (score 2):

If it's' 2012 or 2014, use the `TRY_PARSE()` function:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx

With earlier versions, you have to actualy try to convert it and handle the error:

```
declare @s varchar(10) = 'abc'
declare @isInt bit = 1

begin try
    declare @i int;
    set @i = @s
end try
begin catch
    set @isInt = 0
end catch

select @isInt
```

Comment: I'm afraid I have 2008R2 and 2008(R1 if you will).

Comment: It's a TRY..CATCH then.

Comment: could someone "THUMB UP" my question so that I can THUMB UP your answers please? I don't have enough "reputation" so I cannot score-UP your great answers and this makes me sad!